# Android - Animation while removing items from ListView

Tags: android, listview

I have a ListView in an activity. In each list item there are a text and a CheckBox. On click on the CheckBox, I want to remove the item from the ListView and want to add an animation such as slide down or fade out and then remove.

Any help?

Answer (score 7):

Have a look at my answer

```
protected void removeListItem(View rowView, final int positon) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    final Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(rowView.getContext(), R.anim.splashfadeout);
    rowView.startAnimation(animation);
    Handler handle = new Handler();
    handle.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            array.remove(positon);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            animation.cancel();
        }
    }, 1000);
}
```

call `removeListItem(View rowView, final int positon)` method in onItem click of ListView

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView <? > parent, View rowView, int positon, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText(rowView.getContext(), "" + positon, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        removeListItem(rowView, positon);


    }
});
```

and res/anim/splashfadeout.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
  <alpha xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
  android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator" 
  android:zAdjustment="top" 
  android:fromAlpha="1.0" 
  android:toAlpha="0.0" 
  android:duration="2000" />
```

Full source code of animated ListView [hear](http://pastie.org/3878619)

Comment: This seems to work fine but when you start deleting the last item repeatedly the application would crash with  java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException

Comment: @Teknogenie, I checked it my end, Can you please give me your LogCat.

Comment: I created a project using your source code and when i repeatedly press on the last item it crashed with this exception: http://pastie.org/8297725

Answer (score -1):

You should implement onClickListener on the checkbox in ur adapter class and set visibility of textview GONE or Invisible there or remove item from ur list and call method notifyDataSetChanged() ....

Comment: You have mentioned about to remove item from list, but Shaiful want to implement animation while removing any item from list.